# Is this a linear differential equation $\left(y^2-3x^2\right)\;dy +\left(2xy\right)\;dx=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm confused as to how I get started with this $\left(y^2-3x^2\right)\;dy +\left(2xy\right)\;dx=0$

Is it a linear differential equation?  Appreciate any hints that you can provide.

Comment: No it isn't ... the coefficient of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ should be ONLY function of $x$. You have $y$ term there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not a Linear ODE.
Linear ODE is of the Form below:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n P_i(x)y^{(n)}(x)+P_0(x)y+q(x)=0$$
where $y^{(n)}(x)$ is the n'th derivative of y with respect to x.
But there appear the term $y^2$ which is not linear.
this equation is Homogeneous Differential Equation of the first order.

differential equation of first order of the form $M(x,y)dx+n(x,y)dy=0$ is called complete if $$\frac{\partial M}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$$ but here it's not the case.
However we can make some equation of this form complete with a coefficient called Integral Factor.
The Mechanism is like Below:
$$\mu(x,y)M(x,y)dx+\mu(x,y)n(x,y)dy=0$$ 
now if we have 
$$\frac{\partial (\mu M)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial (\mu N)}{\partial x}$$
then we can solve it. now finding this so called $\mu$.
well solving it using integral factor is almost impossible because Integral Factor is'nt a function of just one of variable $x$ or $y$, thus finding it is as hard as solving the main equation. instead consider this inventive way:
$$y'=\frac{2xy}{3x^2-y^2}$$
after some easy manipulation we get above equation. now we can write:
$$y'=\frac{2\frac{y}{x}}{3-(\frac{y}{x})^2}$$
now we introduce this new variable $\frac{y}{x}=h \Rightarrow y'=h'x+h$ so now we get this: 
$$h'x+h=\frac{2h}{3-h^2} \Rightarrow h'x=\frac{h(h+1)(h-1)}{3-h^2}$$

then we can solve it easily cause now the variables are separable. then with Partial Fraction Expansion and Integrating we get:
$$dh \times (\frac{-3}{h}+\frac{1}{h+1}+\frac{1}{h+1})=\frac{dx}{x}$$

$\Rightarrow $ln$(h-1)-3$ln$(h)+$ln$(h+1)=$ln$x+c \Rightarrow \frac{h^2-1}{h^3}=Cx \Rightarrow Cxh^3-h^2+1=0$

this is a cubic equation and has three solution. but unfortunately solving this equation to get solutions with Cardano's formula is quite complicated. but on bright side we still have the implicit formula for $y(x)$:
$$Cx(\frac{y}{x})^3-(\frac{y}{x})^2+1=0$$

Comment: Thank you, what type of differential equation is it?  I cannot recognize any patterns.

Comment: this is the first order differential equation of the form $y'=f(x,y)$ witch can be solved with integral Factor. I'm on it. indeed second chapter of Boyce.'s book "Elementary Differential equation" http://www.amazon.com/Elementary-Differential-Equations-William-Boyce/dp/047003940X is about this kind

Comment: @free_mind if you do bit of algebra, you will find that it is [homogeneous differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_differential_equation)

Comment: Isn't it a differential form? So is it false that it is 0 iff both the coefficients are 0?

Comment: @K.K.McDonald, your first mistake was at
$$y^{\prime}=\frac{3x^2-y^2}{2xy}$$ Please restart from there. Aside from the homogenous differential equation pattern, it can also be written as [Bernoulli's differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation) $$\frac{dx}{dy}-\frac3{2y}x=-\frac{y}{2}x^{-1}$$

Comment: can you please mention what's the mistake?

Comment: It should read $$y^{\prime}=\frac{2xy}{3x^2-y^2}$$

Comment: Now you've got the right solution in your handwritten notes, but a couple of typos remain. $\left(\frac xy\right)^2$ instead of $\left(\frac yx\right)^2$, two copies of $\frac1{h+1}$ instead of a $\frac1{h-1}$, $ln$ instead of $\ln$, and the arguments to the last two logs are reversed. But these are just errors in transcription; your final answer is correct.

Comment: ok. done and done.